# Can we add UIKit like things to Game

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, app-store-connect, game-physics

I am developing an ios game, which uses less animation & can be implemented via some of `UIKit` features, i don't want to use `SpriteKit` But yes implemented Multiplayer game connectivity via `GKMatchmakerViewController`

My only question is will apple approves this App?(Combination of `UIKit`+ `GKMatchmakerViewController`)

very very thank you in advance for your answers/comments :)

Comment: No one can say what Apple will or will not allow. But in your case I see not issue. As long as your app adhere the guidelines there should not be an issue.

Comment: @rckoenes all right

Comment: No problem about this, you can use all official API. Be careful at performance

Comment: @Simone Pistecchia ok will look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't be a problem at all, but nobody knows what Apple will approve...
You should take a closer look at the guidelines though, but I don't really see a problem with that.

Please keep us up to date if it gets rejected or approved :)

Comment: @Amit In the app I tried it it got approved to AppStore yeah. I guess it will not be a   problem in your project aswell :)

Answer (score 1):

For this reason I have not heard of rejected. It will probably be approved.

Please inform us about the process